# Can we use " RequestContext " in django to update values in div?

Tags: django

I want to update some values in view.

temparature.html

```
<table id="test"><tbody>
<tr>
{% for label, value in temperature.items %}
      <td >{{ label }}</td>
      <td>{{ value }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Can I use the `RequestContext` method in Django to update the values of the temperature variable in the Django HTML template?

Comment: you mean update value live on the template(for example using AJAX)?

Comment: yes, can we update values using  RequestContext   same as using AJAX

Comment: it's not the same as AJAX, `RequestContext` populate the context when a template is rendered with a request so it run before the page finished loading. If you want to update the page without reloading use AJAX to call django rest api to update

Comment: Thank You very much ! for your advice